Is it possible for a controlled MUI TextField to return an object as value?
I'm currently trying to build a custom input component based on the MUI TextField. The input is able to switch between languages so you can edit the value for multiple languages.
The problem I'm facing is that I can just return the input string of the currently selected language when I submit the form. Is there a possibility to return an Object with the full state including all languages to my form?

Code example:
https://playcode.io/1913099
So instead of returning
name: 'english value'

I want the form to return the full state of my input component like:
name: {
  en_EN: 'english value'
  de_DE: 'german value'
}

